# Can we add some padding in the linked questions page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, linked-questions

If a post has [a huge number of linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=MostLinks), we can able to see a link as [see more linked questions...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/76251?lq=1) in the "Linked" section. When clicking on the "see more linked questions" link, the results are opening in a new page.

At the top of the page, there is no space between the text `<n> questions linked to/from <question_title>` and the grid cells. Adding some padding to the text will be looking good.

**Current UI:**

> [image: No space]

**Expected UI:**

> [image: Expected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It appears that the alignment issue was resolved some time ago.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Issue fixed]